# identities for the minimum sum of squares

Tags: least-squares, residuals, generalized-least-squares

The expressions below show identities for the minimum sum of squares (C.R. Rao, 1973). How is the last expression obtained? I'm either missing some steps or there are some typos, but the expression after the first equal sign already is not clear to me.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the fact that $\hat \beta = (X'X)^{-1} X' Y$ would help you.

Comment: I am suprised then that first one is clear to you as it follows directly from $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$ that $X^T(X\hat{\beta} - Y) = 0$ which is used twice here

Comment: @gammer or Łukasz Grad thanks, if you would convert your comment into an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [least squares estimator of $\beta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#The_general_problem) is

$$\hat \beta = (X'X)^{-1} X'Y $$

which gets you to the final line. Some basic factoring gets you to the far right hand side of the final line.